# Black Dots and Lines on Sculpt

Tags: sculpting

I am at the moment in the middle of sculpting a Wyvern. I have gotten very far and I have a lot of progress. But my progression has been hindered because there are weird black lines and dots showing up on the sculpt. I can't remove it and it's a massive nuisance. And it still shows up when rendered. How do I remove these because I have spent a lot of time and I am reall proud of it.

[image]

Comment: Is there a hair particle system enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have particle system enabled for hair?

[image]